# Cannot read properties of undefined reading 'paper'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am using the palette from MUI (5.15.1), It has property background and inside the background I have paper which has default value, but when I am logging the value the palette object does not have the background property, I am using the palette like this -

```
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
export const theme = createTheme({
  palette,
});

export const ThemeWrapper: React.FC<PropsWithChildren<any>> = ({
  children,
}) => <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>;

Here is how ThemeProvider is used - 
import { DefaultTheme } from '@mui/system';
export interface ThemeProviderProps<Theme = DefaultTheme> {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  theme: Partial<Theme> | ((outerTheme: Theme) => Theme);
}
export default function ThemeProvider<Theme = DefaultTheme>(
  props: ThemeProviderProps<Theme>,
): React.ReactElement<ThemeProviderProps<Theme>>;
```

I logged the value of theme it is showing all properties like primary, secondary, contrast but does not contain bakground and paper which is by default provided by MUI, I tried changing the version to 5.15.11 but still the same problem, also I am using gatsby v5.